# Panel and time fixed effects interpretation

Tags: regression-coefficients, fixed-effects-model

I am trying to interpret coefficients in a fixed effects regression.

When including panel fixed effects I obtain:

**depvar=23+0.51indepvar +e**

When including both panel and time fixed effects I get:

**depvar=90+0.67indepvar +e**

Panel is set by country and year. The problem is that there is much higher variation and unobserved heterogeneity between the countries than there is between the years, this is apparent from the within and between standard deviations.

Therefore, I was not expecting to obtain such great difference in constants. How could I interpret obtaining such a drastic difference?

Indeed, if indepvar was equal to zero, my depvar would be 23, which is impossible for my data, as depvar is an index and fluctuates from 85 to 115. How can this be possible?

Comment: Are you referring to differences in the fixed effects? It's impossible to say whether these are substantial or not because we know nothing of the precision of the study. i.e. if there were only 10 observations, 2 clusters over 5 time periods, I would not overinterpret the differences.

Comment: @AdamO I am using observations from 18 years for 18 countries, the source is World Bank. This particular model I am running on a set 10 countries which are supposed to fit the model best. In general, as you can imagine, country differences are quite drastic, but years are not so much, even though I have some crisis periods.  I do not understand how it can be that when I control for only country effects my results are so radically different from when I use both country fixed and time fixed effects.

Comment: I am not worried about the slope coefficients, what troubles me is that my constant is somewhat unrealistic. Could it be due to my "fit the model" country selection?